# Troubles with Insert / Update Methods of DataSet provider for DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I've used a wizard to assert DataGrid with my MSSQL Table using DataSet provider / binding

DataSet model got my table with select / insert / update methods but looking like they don't appear or don't work. I can add / update data from DataGrid but no changes in MSSQL appears.

So here is some code generated by wizards from designers :

this.AlarmView.DataSource = this.alarmDictionaryBindingSource;

```
        // 
        // alarmDictionaryBindingSource
        // 
        this.alarmDictionaryBindingSource.DataMember = "AlarmDictionary";
        this.alarmDictionaryBindingSource.DataSource = this.fRIIBDataSet;
        // 
        // fRIIBDataSet
        // 
        this.fRIIBDataSet.DataSetName = "FRIIBDataSet";
        this.fRIIBDataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;

        // 
        // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1
        // 
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.DataPropertyName = "ID";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.HeaderText = "ID";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1";
        // 
        // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2
        // 
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.DataPropertyName = "Message";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.HeaderText = "Message";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.MaxInputLength = 255;
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Width = 255;
```

Table adapter wizard said that it's generated all methods :
insert , update etc ... But I still can't submit my changes for MSSQL ... What else I need to do ?

That could be easy question but I really can't understand why simple things don't work simply... I will share all necessary information to fix this mess.

I added update method to table manually because wizard LIED to me it was not created and the code :

```
    private void AlarmView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        alarmDictionaryTableAdapter.Update(fRIIBDataSet.AlarmDictionary);
    }
```

works well , but what if I need add new or delete , must I process this all alike that ?

I hope there is more easy way to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commiting the changes you have made using AcceptChanges method of dataset.

Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceab2k93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: ah... Solved ... ID was the problem , my tables request ID :)